# ubuntu 14.04 failure to install or run eclipse adt and android sdk

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse-adt, ubuntu-14.04

Fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install alongside windows 8.1 on brand new system and HDD *UEFI partition.

First steps I took on Ubuntu 14.04 was installing open-jdk-7 and Eclipse with ADT and everything worked correctly.

I wanted Oracle-JDK-7 and to remove open-jdk-7.

I first removed eclipse adt, removed all updates/installs from ADT Package manager then removed open-jdk-7

I installed the Oracle-JDK-7 via the terminal then I reinstalled eclipse adt. eclipse adt will not run correctly or at all now.

the errors I am getting (Not exact word for word) 
*This program will not run, cannot locate adb ddms tools
*Android-sdk-linux/ directory does not exist or cannot locate file or no such archive

when I point eclipse (from within eclipse) to the android-sdk it then switches the error to "cannot run program missing adb ddms tools"

my own troubleshooting so far

re-installed open-jdk-7 alongside oracle-jdk-7 and set default version and default javac to both open-jdk-7 *which I decided I want.

Installed android-sdk standalone (with eclipse removed from system) and extracted to the home directory

From the terminal I entered the directory and bash does not recognize android-sdk-linux claiming there is no such file or directory even though it is clearly there.

I believe I narrowed the problem down to just the Android-sdk which includes the platform tools, not being found for some reason...

I am new to Linux...

I do not know how to set JAVA_HOME in linux/ubuntu 14.04 (not sure if that is relevant to this issue)
I know in windows you must delete metadata. folder before installing eclipse adt again.

In my experience, Eclipse Adt always runs perfect on first time install on new system

In my experience all errors and unstable behavior from eclipse adt show up after I replace original install (on both windows and linux platforms Eclipse ADT never runs the same as first install)

I hope someone may be able to point out something I did or am doing wrong in the current situation and overall as I am stumped as to why Eclipse-ADT will not run after remove and new install.

Is there a specific way to completely remove every trace of eclipse ADT?

Do I have to create a directory from the terminal for eclipse, eclipse adt, android sdk any combination?

Being new to linux I am not even sure if I set up both JDK's correctly or if I caused damage to my overall install.

Please go easy on me guys... I checked things out before resorting to asking, in fact this is my very first question as I usually always figure things out on my own... I am really stumped and not quite comfortable enough with linux Ubuntu 14.04 to mess around with my particular situation any further. I humbly ask for precise instruction on how to get eclipse adt to run and behave the way it did on first install... and also if necessary how to set JAVA_HOME (I want open-jdk for building android aosp and oracle jdk for building apps)

Is it possible in ubuntu 14.04 to install eclipse adt and have it use open-jdk and install android studio and have it use oracle jdk all on the same ubuntu install... how would I go about creating the directories?

I know this is a very lengthy question with alot of details... I must get my Ubuntu 14.04 install production ready asap

Answer (score 3):

I use Eclipse ADT along with Oracle JDK 7 in my ubuntu 14.04.
This is how I have done the setup,

1. Ubuntu comes with Open JDK. No need to remove it. Once you install Oracle JDK , it will become your default JAVA_HOME. So no need to worry much about the configurations.

To Install Oracle JDK 7:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

After installing check with "javac -version" command.

2. Now just get a fresh Eclipse ADT for Linux from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
3. Unzip it , Get into Eclipse directory and open the eclipse executable.

You will be all set to start your android development with Eclipse ADT and Oracle JDK 7.

For Studio, Just get the studio from developer site and execute the studio.sh file which is present inside the bin directory of Studio. Thats it.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you for your input... I originally removed the open jdk because I didnt think I needed it. I installed the oracle jdk the same way you mentioned as well... my problem has been, since removing eclipse adt originally, every install has some kind of problem now when the original ran perfect. I also dont want oracle jdk for eclipse since I am doing android builds not apps which the open jdk is suggested... I have both oracle and open on my system, through the terminal I set open jdk as default and javac is set to open jdk, yet anything associated with android assigns oracle, weird.

Comment: It worked for me, only thing i needed to do is removed the last keyword sudo from the 2nd command. Thank you :)

Comment: thank you for mentioning it. I corrected the command in my post.